# how to get the target's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this work.

If target's parent is .form_contact_div then console.log('keep open form');

code I am using but it is not working for (else if) condition working only for the if and else.

code:

```
jQuery("body").click(function(e) {

    var target = jQuery(e.target);
    console.log(target);

    if(jQuery(target).parents('#contact-btn-div').length 
      && jQuery('#contact-btn-div').hasClass('close')) {
        console.log('keep open btn');
        jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
        jQuery("#contact-btn-div").removeClass('close');
    }
    else if(jQuery(target).parent().is('.form_contact_div')) {
        console.log('keep open form');
        jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
    }
    else{
        console.log('keep close');
        jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '-472px'});
        jQuery("#contact-btn-div").addClass('close');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you wrap your code in a document ready function and pass `$` as param you can save a bunch of bytes, plus it'll look cleaner.

Comment: _note_: `target` variable is already return by `jQuery`, so there is no need to pass it to jQuery again: `jQuery(target)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace e.taget with **this** like

```
var target = $(this);
```

Because you need to get the clicked element as your taget then better to use this and your code should be like this

```
jQuery("body").click(function(e) {

    var target = $(this);
    console.log(target);

    if(target.parent('#contact-btn-div').length 
      && jQuery('#contact-btn-div').hasClass('close')) {
        console.log('keep open btn');
        jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
        jQuery("#contact-btn-div").removeClass('close');
    }
    else if(target.parent().is('.form_contact_div')) {
        console.log('keep open form');
        jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
    }
    else{
        console.log('keep close');
        jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '-472px'});
        jQuery("#contact-btn-div").addClass('close');
   }
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error using this Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'parents'

Answer (score 0):

Check the edited Code.

```
<div id="contact-btn-div" class="close" style="width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid #666; background-color:#F60;">

<div style="width:200px; height:100px; border:1px solid #0FC; background-color:#9CC;"></div>
</div>
```

And The Javascript,

```
$(function(){
$("body").click(function(e) {

var target = $(e.target);
console.log(target);

if(target.parent('#contact-btn-div').length 
  && $('#contact-btn-div').hasClass('close')) {
    console.log('keep open btn');
    $("#contact-btn-div").removeClass('close');
}

});
});
```

I think you will get what you need. Cheers :).

Comment: @Gautam3164: Your $(this) will give BODY Object every time you click on anywhere, That's why your logic will fail. $(e.target) is the only option here. Cheers.